# Chrome DevTools Mobile Emulation scroll not working

Tags: scroll, google-chrome-devtools

Using Google Chrome's DevTools Mobile Emulation, it seems that the touch scroll is not working.

See this test: http://codepen.io/dstj/pen/Datcw

Scrolling works on both an iPad 3's Safari and Android 4.2' Chrome, but does not work in Google DevTools with Touch Screen Emulation.

Another difference I see is that scrollbars appear on DevTools, but not on tablets...

Any ideas why?

Note: Using Chrome Version 33.0.1750.154 m

Comment: Horizontal scrolling works just fine in the Device Mode. So, whatever it was, it's fixed now.

Comment: same thing is happening to me in my website, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesnt.

Comment: Still have this bug Chrome 80.0.3987.132

Comment: is there a chromium bug I could reference to my teammates?

Answer (score 160):

When it happened to me, I closed the tab and launched again. It fixed it.

Comment: Simple and effective. Works for me.

Comment: I spent 2 hours while searching for solution, because I was sure, that trouble was in my code. You save my time!

Comment: closing the tab and opening it in another tab didnt work or did you mean the whole chrome browser?

Comment: urghhh I feel so stupid. The solution is so simple >.<

Comment: For me F5 refresh does the job, I don't have to close/open the tab/browser. I have to do this every time I switch to mobile view

Comment: I just finally relaunched my browser and thought it was something they broke recently in an update. A simple tab close and relaunch with `ctrl+shift+t` worked great for me, thanks!

Comment: Thank you sir, I was searching for it everywhere

Comment: have tried refresh several times, but only reopen work..

Comment: One of a sudden, I thought I became a bad developer. Thanks for this fix. Proof that I'm good. Hey Google. Stop making us doubt ourselves over here. lol

Comment: The best StackOverflow answer ever! Thanks for reminding us to close and relaunch. Been refreshing the page for hundred times already instead of just relaunching. smh.

Comment: "close and open" works always lol. Thanks

Comment:  free upvotes

Comment: This is not a good long-term solution. What if this keeps happening when developing and we don't want to waste time closing tabs?

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem when running Chrome on MacOS. If you know a device width let's say iPad is 768px width then instead of device choose Responsive and enter 768px for width. After that you should be able to scroll.

Comment: This actually works! Annoying, but if you set manually the pixels instead of choosing the device it goes to bottom of page again. Thanks a lot

Comment: Worth noting also in Responsive mode if you leave height blank you can zoom in and still be able to scroll. If you leave it on a specific device and zoom in you won't be able to scroll to the bottom of the screen. It's clear they implemented device height simply by tying it to the viewport height. They are not independently controllable. But be warned, when doing this the page will not render at device height anymore.

Answer (score 3):

In the past I have found touch events to be flaky in chrome dev tools. Turning "Emulate touch screen" off and on again often fixes the problem for me. The page you sent works fine for me on current chrome in mobile emulation mode.

Answer (score -2):

click f5 couple of time and disable and enable  resampling input events.
this works